# Could I see my back using a wormhole?

Tags: wormholes

I was wondering if in a possible future we could see our own back using a wormhole instead of using a couple of mirrors.

Comment: https://curiosity.com/topics/what-would-it-be-like-to-ride-through-a-wormhole-curiosity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wormhole is not necessary for that purpose. All you need is to be close enough to a black hole that a beam of light that leaves a flashlight in your hand is bent into a circle so that it orbits the black hole and illuminates your back.

There are physical consequences associated with doing this which are both unpleasant and irreversible so I cannot recommend it.

Some years ago, Scientific American published a nicely detailed article about this very topic with lots of good illustrations. If I remember when, I will edit 
 & add the issue date here.